# How to register a service worker from a different domain

Tags: html, google-chrome, service-worker, web-push, push-api

I am trying to implement Push Notifications for Google Chrome. I want to register service worker from a different domain.

Example: 
Service Worker Code is located at: https://example.com/

I want to register the service worker (which is located at above domain) from a different domain: https://example2.com/

Is there any way to achieve the same. Because when I try to include the service worker page (example) as an iFrame, the service worker throws an error while registering

> "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Registration failed - permission
>   denied"

Comment: we were able to solve this problem by showing `https://example.com` in a new popup window with `window.open`. not a perfect solution but better than nothing

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem possible as a [`SecurityError`](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#securityerror) exception would be included in the rejected Promise *if the origin of scriptURL is not client's origin*. See the spec on the [Registration Algorithm](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#register-algorithm).

Even if possible, there would be few advantages to do so as the service worker's [`scope`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#service-worker-registration-scope), a URL, must have the same origin as the page that registers the service worker.

About the iFrame, there are restrictions in place to prevent you from throwing an https:  on an http: page and using that to register a service worker. See [DOMException when registering service worker inside an https iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702247/domexception-when-registering-service-worker-inside-an-https-iframe).